# C# Find specific data in a XML File

Tags: c#, xml

I am a beginner in code and i am asking help with a XML file, i made a project to display food menu and create randoms menu too, Starters, Main Course and Dessert will be in different XML files, my problem is that i never got to deal with XML files so i am quite bad.

Actually my software looks like that : https://prnt.sc/qwd4ld (it's in french but tabs are Starter, Main Course and Dessert, then, Pick random menu)

So, my software will need to work like that :

The first Combo box is used to display all names, so it takes every Starters names from the XML and display them in the combobox. (I actually did that)

Then, when i select a Starter in the combobox, the software need to find the description and the recipe in the XML and display that in a listbox(like on my screenshot) (I need to do that)

How my XML file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xmlentrees>
  <entrees>
    <entree>
      <Nomentree>STARTER NAME</Nomentree>
      <descentree>STARTER DESC.</descentree>
      <recette>
        AND
        THERE
        THE
        RECIPE
      </recette>
    </entree>
    <entree>
      <Nomentree>STARTER NAME</Nomentree>
      <descentree>STARTER DESC.</descentree>
      <recette>
        AND
        THERE
        THE
        RECIPE
      </recette>
    </entree>
  </entrees>
</xmlentrees>
```

And here is my c# code

```
#region entree

const string XMLENTREES = @"c:\temp\entree.xml"; // i pasted the xml file in temp cuz if he's in my resources, i can't load it
private List<string> names;
private Dictionary<string, string> dict;
private List<Entree> entrees;


private void xmlentree()
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(XMLENTREES);

    entrees = doc.Descendants("entree").Select(x => new Entree()
        {
            nomentree = (string)x.Element("Nomentree"),
            descentree = (string)x.Element("descentree"),
            recette = (string)x.Element("recette")
        }).ToList();

    dict = entrees.GroupBy(x => x.nomentree, y => y)
                      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

    names = dict.Select(x => x.Key).ToList(); // MY LIST OF STARTERS NAMES

    object[] array = names.ToArray<object>();
    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(array);
}

public class Entree
{
    public string nomentree { get; set; }
    public string descentree { get; set; }
    public string recetteentree { get; set; }
    public string recette { get; set; }
}

#endregion entree


private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (names.Contains(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())) //HERE I CAN CHECK IF THE NAME IN COMBO BOX MATCH WITH MY LIST OF STARTERS NAMES
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the XML using LINQ to XML and pull out the fields you need:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (names.Contains(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())) //HERE I CAN CHECK IF THE NAME IN COMBO BOX MATCH WITH MY LIST OF STARTERS NAMES
        {
            XElement entreeXml = XElement.Load(@"c:\temp\entree.xml");

            var query = (from x in entreeXml.Element("entrees").Elements("entree")
                         where (string)x.Element("Nomentree") == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
                         select new
                         {
                             Description = (string)x.Element("descentree"),
                             Recipe = (string)x.Element("recette")
                         }).SingleOrDefault();

            if (query != null)
            {
                // Set listbox values to query.Description and query.Recipe
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to

1. Create a serializer to convert xml file to a class based data.
2. Deserialize your xml to Xmlentrees class object.
3. Look up Entree based on starter name
4. What i am doing here is printing first one that mathces Start Name.

```
//filename is the complete file name with path.

using TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Xmlentrees));
var allEntrees = (Xmlentrees)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

Entree starter = allEntrees.Entrees.Entree.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Nomentree.Equals("STATERNAME"));
if (starter != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {starter.Nomentree}, Desc: {starter.Descentree}, Recipe: {string.Join(",", starter.Recette)}");
}
```

**Classes needed for deserialization**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "entree")]
public class Entree
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Nomentree")]
    public string Nomentree { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "descentree")]
    public string Descentree { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "recette")]
    public string Recette { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "entrees")]
public class Entrees
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "entree")]
    public List<Entree> Entree { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "xmlentrees")]
public class Xmlentrees
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "entrees")]
    public Entrees Entrees { get; set; }
}
```

If you have xml files and you are not sure how the classes are supposed to be written, use [Xml2Csharp](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) site to automatically convert an xml to classes.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Print method to your class :

```
        public class Entree
        {
            public string nomentree { get; set; }
            public string descentree { get; set; }
            public string recetteentree { get; set; }
            public string recette { get; set; }

            public string Print(Entree entree)
            {
                return string.Format("Norm : {0}\nDescription : {1}\n Recette : {2}",
                    entree.nomentree, entree.descentree, entree.recetteentree);
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello**, thanks for all your answers, my problem is solved and it works fine !

Jawad, about the XML2CSharp, i wasn't knowing that but i will use it next time i need to work with XML to try it, thanks for sharing that !